# How to count the number of occurrences of Hashmaps with an specific key in a array of Hashmaps?

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

I need to know how many hashmaps have the specific key in an array of hashmaps.

How can I get that number without going through the whole array in a loop? something like

```
int occurrences = Collections.frequency(TheHashmapArray, ["specificKey",*]);
```

Comment: Why don't you want to loop? How many hashmaps do you have? `containsKey` has a pretty much negligible complexity for a typical HashMap.

Answer (score 3):

From a performance standpoint, there's no way of achieving this without going through all the maps, with O(n) complexity (note that `containsKey` has a O(1) complexity in a `HashMap`).

If the issue is just avoiding the clunky syntax of writing a loop, Java 8 offers a neat way of doing this with streaming APIs:

```
Map<String, String>[] mapsArray = // get the value
long numMaps =
    Arrays.stream(mapsArray).filter(p -> p.containsKey("some_key")).count();
```

EDIT:
According to the comment bellow, it's not an array, but an `ArrayList`. The same principal still holds, but since you have an actual `Collection`, you could just call `.stream`:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mapsArray =  // get the value
long numMaps = mapsArray.stream().filter(p -> p.containsKey("some_key")).count();
```

Comment: thanks, but my array is defined like a ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>, How must be the sintax?

Comment: @Dov oh, I thought it was an actual array. An `ArrayList` is something different - it's a built-in collection that implements the `List` interface backed by an internal array. Anyway, see my edit - the principle is similar although the syntax is slightly different.